# How to add to 'Common Expressions" in Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

In Expression Builder dialog of Microsoft Access there is an entry for Common Expressions.  Can I add my own expressions to that list?

Comment: shouldn't this be over at stackoverflow?

Comment: I think there is no clear delineation between the two sites. The bigots over at SO want to treat just about any Access question that doesn't involve code pounding as a non-programming question, despite the fact that the results of what you do in Access with point-and-click usually require significant lines of code in just about any other front-end development platform. I'm not sure these two sites should have an independent existence, but these are meta observations and don't really belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Create an expression](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA011813841033.aspx):

> In the Expression Builder, Access
>   includes some common expressions that
>   you can use for page numbering.

I believe there are only a few such expressions, dealing with page numbers, date/time values and current user. And that you can't add to them.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the "Common Expressions" list is generated by Access as it notices you using certain expressions, well, commonly :)

I *believe* it's similar to how Excel will eventually change the list of frequent functions you can insert when you go to Insert -> Function.